# Problems while installing pst-barcode

Tags: pstricks, barcodes, pst-barcode

I tried to install [pst-barcode](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=pst-barcode), but after moving the files to `/usr/share/texmf/dvips/pstricks/` and running `texhash`, I still can't use them, and have to enter the files manually when compiling the document.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you want to install the package? It is already part of any known TeX distribution, like TeXLive or MiKTeX. The reason why it should already be present or installable via an update manager. A rpm package can be found with `rpmfind.net`:

It is texlive-pstricks: http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=texlive-pstricks

Comment: I don't see it in the repos of Fedora 14. A `yum provides \*/pst-barcode.sty` doesn't turn up anything either.

Comment: it should be in `texlive-collection-pstricks`

Comment: As of Fedora 16, I don't see any such package :-( is it bundled in any third-party Yum Repository or some-such?

Comment: It is `texlive-pstricks`: http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=texlive-pstricks